# Поиск по List<>

Tags: c#, коллекции

Допустим есть класс

```
public class Information
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    public int Age;
}
```

Есть еще один класс:

```
public class InfoByCities
{
    public List<InFormation> Moscow;
    public List<InFormation> Saint_Petersburg;
    public List<InFormation> Rostov;
}
```

Заполняем эти `List<>`:

```
InfoByCities fill = new InfoByCities();
int Amount = 1500;

fill.Moscow = new List<Information>(Amount);
for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
{
     Information inf = new Information();
     inf.Name = "Саша"+ i.ToString();
     inf.Surname = "Поляков" + i.ToString();
     inf.Age = i;
     fill.Moscow.Add(inf);
}

fill.Saint_Petersburg = new List<Information>(Amount); 
for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
{
     Information inf = new Information();
     inf.Name = "Пётр" + i.ToString();
     inf.Surname = "Поляков" + i.ToString();
     inf.Age = i;
     fill.Saint_Petersburg.Add(inf);
}

fill.Rostov = new List<Information>(Amount);
for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
{
     Information inf = new Information();
     inf.Name = "Саша" + i.ToString();
     inf.Surname = "Петухов" + i.ToString();
     inf.Age = i;
     fill.Rostov.Add(inf);
}
```

Вопрос: Как можно реализовать поиск по всем `List<>`, не обращаясь к каждому индивидуально. К примеру, найти по всех трех спискам людей с именем "Саша". Количество `List<>` может быть намного больше.

Comment: У вас три (и говорите, что может быть и больше) сущности `List`. Как вы вы вообще видите поиск в коллекции не обращаясь к ней напрямую? И у вас все три сущности имеют один и тот же тип, следовательно, искать можно в любом из списков одинаково.
На мой взгляд, выглядеть это может так: а) Делаем список списков (т.е. контейнер, где будут храниться переменные `Moscow`, `Saint_Petersburg`, `Rostov` и другие). И вот делаем поиск уже там, перебирая содержимое каждой переменной. Либо б) — можно сделать 1 список для поиска `List<InFormation> Search`, куда добавляем содержимое всех листов и ищем.

Comment: Но вообще я бы сделал не так. Список типа `Information` был бы один, но в сам класс `Information` добавить поле `City`, например. А еще у вас опечатка в коде - сравните: `InFormation` и `Information`.

Comment: Как раз таки б вариант у меня щас в программе и используется.Но очень медленный.На счет опечатки:Я просто привел пример на счет городов,имен,и так далее.Писал код здесь,поэтому и мог ошибку допустить.Все List<> имеют один и тот же тип.

Comment: Если всё дело в скорости поиска, то следует подумать о другом подходе. Например, вместо `List` (поиск O(n)) использовать `HashSet` (поиск O(1)), или `SortedList` (поиск O(log n)). Также смотрите [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). Ну и можно попробовать распараллелить поиск.

Comment: Спасибо.Но я нашел другой способ который более подходит и не касается поиск в List<>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть переменная `fill` типа `InfoByCities`.
Для начала надо объединить списки:

```
var informations = new List<List<Information>>
{
    fill.Moscow, fill.Saint_Petersburg, fill.Rostov
};

var informationArray = informations.SelectMany(i => i).ToArray();
```

Далее делаем LINQ-запросы:

```
var sashas = informationArray.Where(i => i.Name == "Саша").ToArray();
```